# Extra information within a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with some items in it and I would like to know how to add extra information to the side of this? I have a photoshopped example below of what I mean, it's difficult to describe without an image or I would have used google to try and find the answer myself. I want it with the extra text on the right hand side, i've seen it done easily within the iPhone but i'm a bit stuck with android. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's easy in Android too, you need to create a custom layout for a list item and set up an adapter to write to the fields of your new layout. [here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) an example.

Comment: Haha, yeah I've learned there's no logic to the amount of votes an answer gets. @.@ My shortest answers seem to get more than the ones I put a lot of work into. Here's another +1 for the hell of it. :)